# Poco - set infinite socket receive timeout

Tags: c++, poco-libraries

I am using Poco::Net::Socket as [documented here](http://pocoproject.org/docs/Poco.Net.Socket.html)

What do I pass to the `setReceiveTimeout` function to cause the receive to never time out?

So far I have set it to a large number of seconds, using `.setReceiveTimeout( Poco::Timespan(86400, 0) );` but would like a cleaner solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default socket receive timeout is already infinity.

Do nothing.

To restore infinity after setting a finite timeout, use a value of zero.

Comment: I've previously set it to non-infinite and then want to do an infinite read on the same socket

Comment: OK. If zero means infinite timeout, is there any way to signal no timeout?

Comment: If you mean returning immediately if there is no data, you would have to use MSG_NOWAIT or `select()` if Poco has them, or else non-blocking mode.